# Symfony2 Authentication fails silently with custom UserProvider

Tags: php, symfony

I tested the in_memory authentication, and database authentication with the their default UserProvider, it works fine, but when i specify a costum userProvider, it fails silently, i am using a form to login, it just refreshes the page, and i am still not authenticated.

Costum Userprovider:

```
namespace Snap\ModelBundle\Security;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UnsupportedUserException;
use Snap\RestBundle\Entity\User;

class WebserviceUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface {

    private $em;

    public function __construct($em) {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function loadUserByUsername($username) {

        $userData = $this->em
                ->getRepository('SnapRestBundle:User')
                ->findOneBy(array('username' => $username));

        // make a call to your webservice here
        // pretend it returns an array on success, false if there is no user

        if ($userData) {
            return $userData;
        }

        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(sprintf('Username "%s" does not exist.', $username));
    }

    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user) {
        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            throw new UnsupportedUserException(sprintf('Instances of "%s" are not supported.', get_class($user)));
        }

        return $this->loadUserByUsername($user->getUsername());
    }

    public function supportsClass($class) {
        return $class === 'Snap\ModelBundle\Entity\User';
    }

}
```

Security.yml

```
security:
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            pattern:    ^/
            anonymous:  ~
            provider: users
            form_login:
                login_path: snap_front_login
                check_path: login_check

    encoders:
        Snap\RestBundle\entity\User: plaintext

    providers:
            users:
                id: webserviceUserProvider           

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_USER:        ROLE_USER
        ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN]
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH ]

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Comment: What does your login Action looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the following code is not returning a class implementing the `UserInterface` interface:

```
  if ($userData) {
        return $userData;
    }
```

You need to return an instance of a class that implements the [`UserInterface`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/a8acbf8fed2a4244715ea7aa8f5f367f8c08bcba/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/UserInterface.php?source=c) interface.

From Symfony official documentation, "[How to create a custom User Provider](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html)":

> (...) you'll need to create a User class that represents that data. The User
>   can look however you want and contain any data. The only requirement
>   is that the class implements UserInterface.

**Example**

For example this is how the [`InMemoryUserProvider`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/51c6d7696c2fb98f7720d842c502662e6451f925/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/InMemoryUserProvider.php?source=c) creates a User instance:

```
return new User($user->getUsername(), $user->getPassword(), $user->getRoles(), $user->isEnabled(), $user->isAccountNonExpired(),
                $user->isCredentialsNonExpired(), $user->isAccountNonLocked());
```